# Is it possible to use css variables inside inline svg?

Tags: css, svg, css-variables, inline-svg

I am writing a userstyle for a website, I use css variables for configuration by the user. I am trying to use inline svg with a variable in it to create a checkmark set to the user's preferred accent color. But it doesn't seem to work.

In the code provided I just jammed in the var function, but I've also tried setting the color of the stroke to currentColor and setting the color of the element to the variable. Setting the mask and background-color work but I want a "pure inline svg" solution.

```
.checkmark {
    background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="12">\
    <path fill="none" stroke="var(--ColAccent)" stroke-width="3" d="M1.99609375 5.7835338l3.70287382 3.7028738L14.1853752 1"/>\
</svg>');
}
```

The checkmark should be accent color. When I set it by simply putting in the var() it doesn't work and is transparent. Interestingly, when using the currentColor method, the stroke is black.

Comment: In fact you're confusing dataURLs with inline svgs. dataURLs can't be accessed/manipulated from the main CSS. An inlined svg residing in your page's HTML could be changed.

Answer (score 5):

This is working:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="12" style="--ColAccent:red">
    <path fill="none" style="stroke:var(--ColAccent)" stroke-width="3" d="M1.99609375 5.7835338l3.70287382 3.7028738L14.1853752 1"/>
</svg>
```

This is **not** working:

```css
background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' style='--ColAccent:red' width='16' height='12'%3E%3Cpath fill='none' style='stroke:var(--ColAccent)' stroke-width='3' d='M1.99609375 5.7835338l3.70287382 3.7028738L14.1853752 1'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A")'
```

For a solution to your problem I would use javascript:

```js
let _checkmark = document.querySelector(".checkmark");
let ColAccent = _checkmark.style.getPropertyValue("--ColAccent");
_checkmark.style.backgroundImage = `url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='12'%3E%3Cpath fill='none' stroke='${ColAccent}' stroke-width='3' d='M1.99609375 5.7835338l3.70287382 3.7028738L14.1853752 1'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A")`
```

```css
.checkmark {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkmark" style="--ColAccent:skyBlue" ></div>
```

Comment: I am creating a userstyle, I can't really use javascript

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to directly use css variables inside inline svg because the inline svg isn't directly in the DOM and you can't target it using css (i.e., there is no way to target the svg from `.checkmark` class. The only other option is to use javascript `getPropertyValue` to get the value of the css variable `--ColAccent` and use it to create a url string with a valid colorname (i.e., `red`) or URI encoded color value (i.e., `%23f00` which is decoded to `#f00`) for `stroke`. Since you can't use javascript, I can't think of any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Styling inline SVGs with CSS is perfectly doable and (in my opinion) is the best option for dealing with SVG UI elements (custom-fonts being my second favorite), but **you can't override attributes on the element**, so (for example) `<path fill=....>` will not be affected by a rule specifying `fill` on the path (well, maybe "!important" will work… but just don't).

E.g. I've written [an icon library](https://ui.xinjs.net/?icons.ts) that renders inline SVGs on demand and, crucially, doesn't apply any explicit `fill` or `stroke` to the `<path>` elements.

Another important thing is `fill` and `stroke` accept different values than (for example) `background-color` and `border-color`.